# Excel exact match searchable matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im sure this is a very simple problem but have done a search and cant find my solution or any that I can adapt. Its quite difficult to describe so will use pics and try to explain.
I am putting together a database of jobs. All jobs will have the same variables with a "Y" or "N" specific to that job . I want to be able to have a searchable row where I enter "Y" or "N" & it matches any job with an exact match. Hope that made sense here are the pics that will help.

[image]

Im sure I have done similar to this before but as I dont use excel everyday I am struggling to put what i have found to good use.
Any help would be much appreciated & I thank you in advance.

Comment: I have been playing around with youtube tutorials with no success. I have nothing that is even close to be able to show. The database will be where previous completed jobs are entered. They will all have their own variables. The searchable area is where variables can be entered to find a similar job. It needs to be an exact match. I have in the past used Vlookup but his only every been based on a job number. This is like the reverse where I am entering the info to find job numbers that match

Comment: Maybe use a `=COUNTIF()` for each column in your "database". Then, you can use a `=MATCH()` function to find the location whatever you are looking for. For example. countif would be 2 for `Y,Y`, 1 for `N,Y`. If you wanted to find the `Y,Y`, use a match for 2. I have no idea if this is what you actually want or not..

Comment: Let me preface this with "I can't see your image" in case it has something counter to my suggestion - Couldn't you just use a pivot table? And filter for "Y" on the variables that you wanted, to see matching jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there is one thing you need to do for the solution i am going to provide.

Insert a column left of your data or move everything one column to the right.

In the blank cell `A4` type `=C4&D4&E4&F4&G4&H4&I4&J4&K4&L4&M4&N4` and copy down i.e to cell `A5` in your example.

Do the same in `A11` i.e. `=C11&D11&...`
In cell `B11` write the following function `=vlookup(A11 , $A$4:$B$5 , 2, 0 )`

One thing you should be aware of.
if the strings of `Y` and `N` in your search area match more than 1 jobs it will return the first one it finds.

Comment: Thanks so much this works perfectly. I did have to change the following with a 1 at the end at was getting N/A values =VLOOKUP(A11, $A$4:$B$6, 2, 1 )

Comment: You shouldn't change it to 1. Getting a `N/A` means that the search string does not have a corresponding job. Putting a `1` means an approximate match which is something that (i guess) you do not want.

Comment: Ok I have changed back to a 1. It does not show a result other than #N/A unless I copy paste into the searchable area.  I do have Data Validations running on both database and searchable areas for the Y and N values

Comment: It seems strange. can you check that the formula in cell `A11` is `=C11&D11&E11&F11&G11&H11&I11&J11&K11&L11&M11&N11`

Comment: The problem is, for some reason the formula in the A column was adding a space randomly. I have removed the Data validation & it seems to have cured it. Very strange :-S